# Cannot parse Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header field in preflight response

Tags: angular, http-headers, response-headers, preflight

I am getting a very odd error that is saying that the preflight response cant be parsed properly.

```
/endpoint:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url endpont' from origin 'https://origin' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cannot parse Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header field in preflight response
```

This is the first time I have seen this error as is with most of my team.

Even odder this is not happening in my Dev environment but other environments are affected.

From what I have been told/seen the ws02 settings, okta settings, and httpd.conf settings are the same across environments.

It feels like there is a setting I am missing (okta,ws02, and httpd.conf are controlled by another team)

This is happening on both the domain as well as localhost:8080 configured to the affected environments (again works when configured to dev)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, in the affected environments the app did not exist but also was subscribed to the correct rest api's not sure how that happened but fixing it worked